# how fix "Your query does not include the specified expression '[Invoice Paid Date]' as part of an aggregate function."?

Tags: sql

I am pretty much naive in SQL so please bear with me.
From another workbook, I am trying to select distinct records after doing groupby orderby. But at the time of query, I am getting error message: "Your query does not include the specified expression '[Invoice Paid Date]' as part of an aggregate function."

I am trying below SQL.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [Worker],[Time Sheet End Date], Sum([Time Sheet Billable Hours]),First([Invoice ID]),First([Invoice Status]), Sum([Invoice Paid Amount]), Sum([Total Invoice Amount]), First([Invoice Paid Date]), First([Initial Invoice submit date]) FROM [Timesheet_and_Invoice_Details$A2:Q5000] Where [Worker] Is Not Null  GROUP BY [Worker], [Time Sheet Status], [Time Sheet End Date] Order by [Invoice Paid Date] Desc;
```

I tried MAX function for [Invoice Paid Date] column as well but it is not helping.

**Input:**
[image: Input_Data]

**Required Output:**
[image]

Comment: I am building excel macro to query from another workbook.

Comment: I am using this post as base for my code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723473/sum-and-group-vba-sheet

Comment: At time of creating question, StackOverFlow told me that, it will be better if I include the application that I am working with. That is why I added tag for excel and VBA.

Comment: My guess is you need `Order by First([Invoice Paid Date]) Desc`

Comment: Thank you @CDP1802 your method worked for me. If you add it as answer then I will be able to mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should help:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [Worker],[Time Sheet End Date]
    , Sum([Time Sheet Billable Hours]),First([Invoice ID]),First([Invoice Status])
    , Sum([Invoice Paid Amount]), Sum([Total Invoice Amount])
    , First([Invoice Paid Date]) AS IPD, First([Initial Invoice submit date])
FROM [Timesheet_and_Invoice_Details$A2:Q5000]
Where [Worker] Is Not Null
GROUP BY [Worker], [Time Sheet Status], [Time Sheet End Date] Order by IPD Desc;
```

I added 'IPD' alias. Or just use "Order by First([Invoice Paid Date]) Desc", it's depending of data access provider drivers.

It's due to '[Invoice Paid Date]' is not in the result. 'First([Invoice Paid Date])' is not the same as '[Invoice Paid Date]'.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. But now I am getting a different kind of error "No value given for one or more required parameters." whereas, if I remove orderby clause, it works without any issue.

Comment: Is that all you can be thankful for?

Comment: If you really need to order the result I can suggest

Comment: Or you can follow @CDP1802's comment, it's depending  of data access provider drivers.